# using a combination of css and jquery to position position a new element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay So this is kind of a strange question I have a footer on my page that when elements are hovered over I use jquery to `show()` an inner `<div style="display: none;" >` However I am trying to position the element such that the newly reveled `<div>` sit's on top of the footer

This would be fairly simple if I new the height of the element I was revealing but this is dependent on screen size and therefor is an unknown.

So how can I get it to always be positioned just on top of the footer.

Also I would like to center the newly revealed element relative to the page

here is a little --> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBrS7/2/) <-- i put together to demonstrate the problem

or you can check out the problem on the stagging site --> taken down

Again i would like the newly reveled element to be centered within the page and positioned just above the footer but can not quite figure out how to accomplish this

(hope this make sense) 
Thanks In advance for any help in one of or both parts of a solution!

Comment: If you're relying on jQuery anyway, why not just get the height via jQuery when you unhide the element?

Comment: @SombreErmine This is a good question .. I normaly just fiddle with css `top` to get the exact position i like but can't seem to figure out the logic to do it in jquery

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: my appologies.. was unsave and when updated changes url ... I have found a solution to my problem though using jquery `.offset()` style property will be posting my answer shortly

Comment: Then add it as a solution and close it out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so once I discovered jquery .offset() style property I was off to the races as @SombreErmine pointed out in the comment I just found the offset of the footer element and then calculated the height of the newly revealed element. With the newly reveled elemnet having `position: absolute;` it was easy to use jquery offset(cordinates) to properly place in poistion:

here is the new --> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvU9r/3/) <-- revealing the new method